# Show form in a modal window with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, shopify-app

I want to show a form in a modal window but I have my buttons on my javascript, so I would want to make them the "submit button" of the form.

This is my code:

I open the modal with this javascript function, with 2 buttons:

**modal.js**

```
window.newModal = function(path, title){
  ShopifyApp.Modal.open({
    src: path,
    title: title,
    height: 400,
    width: 'large',
    buttons: {
      primary: {
        label: "OK",
        message: 'modal_ok',
        callback: function(message){
          ShopifyApp.Modal.close("ok");
        }
      },
      secondary: {
        label: "Cancel",
        callback: function(message){
          ShopifyApp.Modal.close("cancel");
        }
      }
    },
  }, function(result){
    if (result == "ok")
      ShopifyApp.flashNotice("'Ok' button pressed")
    else if (result == "cancel")
      ShopifyApp.flashNotice("'Cancel' button pressed")
  });
}
```

And this is my form:

**form_page.html.erb**

```
<section>
 <section class="full-width" align="center">
  <article>
    <div class="card" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
      <form method="POST" action="form_page">
      <input name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" type="hidden">
      <div class="row">
            <label>Dirección:</label>
            <input type="text" name="address"/>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <label>Apt, suite, etc. (opcional):</label>
            <input type="text" name="addressopt"/>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <label>Código Postal:</label>
            <input type="text" name="postal" pattern="[0-9]{5}"/>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <label>Phone (opcional):</label>
            <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{9}" name="phone"/>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
       <label>City:</label>
            <select name="city">
              <option>Madrid</option>
              <option>Barcelona</option>
              <option>Málaga</option>
            </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </article>
```

How can I submit that form through that function buttons?

Comment: Did you find any solution of it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ShopifyApp ever, but in general if you want to submit a form in javascript you can just call `submit()` on the element. You'd want to give an id to the form to find it easily.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp